# Is there an environment to auto update all my website's page headers when I add new pages?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently managing my personal website portfolio and I'd like to add more pages, but I don't want to change the header on each of my previous pages every time I add content. Is there some way to do this automatically? I'm fairly new and use bootstrap for a lot of it.

This seems like something that should exist, but I can't find anything about it when I search.

Answer (score 1):

If your developing in php, you would only have to create one file to act as your header. You could do the same for the footer, asides, or any other modules. See here, http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php.

This is pretty simple even if you don't have much php experience since all you'd be doing is... include "filename.php"

Comment: Adding to the answer here, WordPress follows a similar concept.You separate the header and the footer into different components, and just include them in your pages.